# Время создания переменной

Tags: c++, static

Например, есть искусственный пример:
...

```
int main() {
    /*
        некоторый код
    */
    ...{
        static int someVal = 42;
    }
}
```

Когда произойдет создание переменной? Во время запуска программы или когда доберемся до нужной инструкции?

Comment: Вопрос поставлен криво. В чем "искусственность" примера и в чем "не искусственность"? Использовав тип `int` вы сразу ограничили вопрос, ибо для типа `int` ответ будет сильно отличаться от ответа для типа `std::string`. `int` - это "искусственность" или нет?

Comment: @AnT под "искусственностью" я имел в виду абстрактный пример

Comment: Так мой вопрос именно к том, какие его части взяты наугад "с потолка" (абстрактно), а какие - существенны. Как я понимаю, `static` - существенная часть вопроса. Расположение объявления в блоке, предполагаю, - тоже существенная часть вопроса. А вот `int` - существенная часть вопроса или взят "с потолка"? Инициализатор в виде константного выражения - существенная часть вопроса или взят "с потолка"? Остается только догадываться....

Comment: @AnT ваше замечание справедливо. int я взял "с потолка", подразумевая какой-либо тип...

Comment: OK. Я просто хотел заметить, что `int` (или любой другой скалярный тип) - это плохой кандидат на роль "какого-либо типа", ибо скалярные типы в данном контексте ведут себя особенным образом.

Comment: Зависит от компилятора

Comment: @Андрей Шпилевой: Нет, никакой детектируемой на уровне языка зависимости от компилятора тут нет. Какой-то потенциал зависимости от компилятора есть у сценариев, в которых возникает пресловутое "static initialization order fiasco". Но это совсем другая история.

Comment: Ну, раз пошла речь о конкурсе... поскольку мой ответ написан давно, я просто существенно его дополнил, прошу его перечитать :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Вопрос не имеет однозначного ответа, ибо ответ на него в общем случае критически зависит от типа объекта. В вашем конкретном примере с типом `int` - объект всегда создается строго во время запуска программы.

А в общем случае это зависит от того, что вы называете "созданием".

У объектов в С++ есть "период хранения" (storage duration) и "время жизни" (lifetime).

- Период хранения - это период выделения-освобождения "сырой" памяти, занимаемой объектом.

  Период хранения любых статических объектов - это всегда безусловно все время выполнения программы.
- Время жизни - это период между [нетривиальной] инициализацией и [нетривиальной] деструкцией объекта в этой сырой памяти. Время жизни всегда вложено в период хранения. Время жизни зависит от свойств объекта.

  Если инициализация объекта тривиальна (т.е. если это не-класс тип или класс тип, инициализируемый тривиальным конструктором по умолчанию), то конструкции не требуется вообще и начало *периода хранения* автоматически является началом *времени жизни*.

  Аналогично если деструкция объекта тривиальна (т.е. если это не-класс тип или класс тип с тривиальным деструктором), то *время жизни* длится до конца *периода хранения*.

  Если статический объект требует нетривиальной конструкции, то она будет выполнена в момент первого прохода процесса выполнения по объявлению объекта (если такой момент вообще наступит).

Также, если объект скалярного типа (такого как тип `int`) инициализируется константным выражением, то такая инициализация будет выполнена *статически* (еще на старте программы). Если же выражение неконстантно, на старте программы такой объект будет инициализирован нулем, а инициализация выражением будет выполнена позже, *динамически*. В случае объекта, объявленного локально, это произойдет в момент первого прохода процесса выполнения по объявлению объекта (если такой момент вообще наступит).

В вашем случае вы имеет дело со статическим объектом типа `int`. *Период хранения* такого объекта - все время выполнения программы. И так как это не-класс тип, *время жизни* этого объекта - все время выполнения программы. Также язык гарантирует вам, что инициализация этого объекта делается статически - не во время первого прохода выполнения по объявлению этого объекта, а сразу на старте программы.

Например, вот такой код гарантированно выведет `42`

```
// Продолжительность хранения `i` уже началась
// Время жизни `i` уже началось
// `i` уже проинициализировано значением 42
int main()
{
goto skip;    
  static int i = 42; // Статическая инициализация
skip:
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

А вот такой гарантированно выведет `0`

```
// Продолжительность хранения `i` уже началась
// Время жизни `i` уже началось
// `i` уже проинициализировано значением 0
int main()
{
goto skip;    
  static int i = std::rand(); // Динамическая инициализация
skip:
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Если вы замените `int` на `std::string`, то период хранения такого объекта - все равно все время выполнения программы. А вот время жизни этого объекта начнется тогда, когда выполнение в первый раз пройдет по его объявлению (если такой момент вообще наступит).

Например, вот такой код

```
// Продолжительность хранения `s` уже началась
// Время жизни `s` еще не началось
// Однако все члены `s` уже проинициализированы нулями
int main()
{
goto skip;    
  static std::string s = "Hello World!"; // Динамическая инициализация и начало жизни
skip:
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

увидит объект `s`, по которому уже успел проехаться каток огульной нулевой инициализации, но конструкции еще не выполнялось. Время жизни объекта так и не началось. Поведение не определено.

Comment: По крайней мере `g++ -O` в x86_64 GNU/Linux для первого main с `goto skip;` **не создает** `i` в памяти (и число 42 присутствует в программе только как часть команды `movl $42, %esi`). А вот без оптимизации `i` появляется в сегменте данных (и она уже инициализирована числом 42 в a.out)

Comment: @avp: Это поведение к языку, как таковому, отношения не имеет. Вопрос-то был языковый. А что там нагенерируют компиляторы в рамках правила "as if" - об этом вне конкретного контекста говорить никакого смысла нет. По наблюдаемому поведению данного кода невозможно сказать, что переменная `i` была удалена. Значит она существует. Значит она с нами. А что вы там увидели в сгенерированном коде - это еще вопрос интерпретации увиденного...

Comment: AnT, в общем "языковом" случае согласен с вами. Если бы не полез разбираться, сам *всегда бы считал*, что уж `static int` создается и инициализируется во время компиляции и *независимо от оптимизации*. А тут сюрприз. Оптимизатор выбрасывает переменную. Что еще интересно, так gdb видит ее значение (даже в оптимизированном коде), **но не видит адреса** (его в самом деле нет!), говорит -- `Can't take address of "i" which isn't an lvalue.` (я, понятно, не обобщаю. Просто делюсь наблюдениями...)

Comment: На практике это может быть интересно только если мы попробуем "приаатачиться" к подобной программе и захотим поменять что-то в ее памяти (или для других хаков)

Comment: @avp: Хм... `static` подразумевает internal linkage или no linkage (как в данном случае). Видеть такую переменную (или функцию) выброшенной или соптимизированной - не удивительно, ибо компилятору об этой переменной (или функции) сразу известно все.

Comment: Вот такой [код](http://ideone.com/A2jDMk) в GCC выводит адрес в s - 0. C одной стороны логично - выделена память, и память обнулена. Но с другой - конструктора по умолчанию у Test нет, переменная не создана - просто выделена память! Допустим, что поле s==0 у этого класса вообще недопустимо - можно ли считать, что переменная **создана**? Да, выделена память, да, даже как-то предсказуемо инициализирована - но **допустимо** ли инициализирована? Мне кажется, что говорить о **создании** переменной не приходится...

Comment: @Harry Совершенно верно, не приходится. В данном случае объект инициализируется при помощи нетривиальной инициализации (нетривиальная инициализация - инициализация конструктором, отличным от тривиального умолчательного). Это означает, что время жизни объекта еще не началось. Такие "недообъекты" можно использовать ограниченным числом способов. Но вызов нестатического метода или доступ к нестатическому полю - это неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 12):

При *первом* выполнении кода.

Можно убедиться, создавая, например, переменную некоторого класса с конструктором.

```
struct Test
{
    Test(int x) { cout << x << endl; }
};


int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        static Test t = 42;
    }
}
```

Получим

```
0
42
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

А что такое создание переменной, как не вызов конструктора? :)

**Update**

Так вот, уточняем - что такое **создание переменной**? Выделенное место в памяти можно ли считать созданием переменной? вряд ли, потому что в общем случае это всего лишь место в памяти, которое становится **переменной** определенного типа только после **трактовки** данного места в памяти как переменной данного типа.

Скорее всего - хотя от компилятора это и не требуется! - **место для такой переменной** будет выделено еще на этапе компиляции. Вполне вероятно, что для простого типа вроде `int`, `double` или `char[]` - память будет сразу же соответствующим образом заполнена. **Но это не означает создания переменной**. Как переменная этот кусок памяти будет трактоваться при первом обращении к ней, при ее *первом входе в область видимости*. Если это что-то посложнее простого `int` - то первое обращение будет заключаться в вызове конструктора. Если нет - конструктор вызван не будет, но, независимо от типа переменная возникает только сейчас!

Потому что никто не запрещает - никакой стандарт - выделить компилятору под эту переменную динамическую память при первом выполнении функции. То, **как поступают** реальные компиляторы, никакого отношения к вопросу создания переменной не имеет.

Надеюсь, я более-менее понятно донес мысль?

И напомню еще раз - компилятор имеет огромные права по переиначиванию программы - лишь бы она работала так, как будто она работает, как написано.

Comment: Наглядный пример. Спасибо!)

Comment: Visual Studio не создала "переменной" вообще, она сделала push 42 еще на этапе компиляции кода.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Попробуйте заставить вызвать конструктор до `main`... :) Дело в принципе "как если бы". Оптимизатор может переставлять что угодно и как угодно, лишь бы работало "как если бы" выполнялось, как написано. Поэтому никакими внутренними экспериментами у хорошо написанного компилятора вы не определите, что переменная создана до первого выполнения - а значит, о чем говорить? С **точки зрения языка** она создана при первом выполнении и все тут.

Comment: @Harry: В общем случае: нет, разумеется. Во-первых, говорить о конструкторе можно только в случае типов с конструкторами. А кострукторы есть не у всех типов. У `int` конструктора нет. Во-вторых, правила статической и динамической инициализации четко оговорены стандартом языка. Если язык требует статической инициализации - она будет сделана на старте программы или даже ранее (те. прошита компилятором в сегменте инициализированных данных). Это не говоря еще о том, что есть еще опциональная инициализация нулями, идущая перед динамической инициализацией.

Comment: +1 Вопрос был именно в том, как ведет себя подобная статическая переменная, а оптимизация - дело десятое.

Answer (score 7):

Подозреваю, что зависит от дальнейшего кода и/или настроек компилятора.
Такой пример

```
static int someVal = 42;
printf ("0x%X", someVal);
```

Дает на выходе такой код:

```
.text:0040101E                 push    42
.text:00401020                 push    offset Format   ; "0x%X"
.text:00401025                 call    esi ; __imp__printf
```

То есть переменной как таковой и нет, компилятор соптимизировал ее в константу.
А вот такой код:

```
printf ("0x%X", someVal);
someVal++;
printf ("0x%X", someVal);
```

Приводит к созданию глобальной переменной, инициализированной во время компиляции.

Answer (score 0):

Странно, что на такой простой вопрос фактически никто не дал прямого нормального ответа. Масса рассуждений о времени жизни и какой то "сырой" памяти. Даже как то грустно. На самом деле последний ответ ближе всего к правильному, но какой то неуверенный.

### В итоге ответ такой:

- Все глобальные и статические переменные не требующие конструирования
  создаются и инициализируются на этапе **компиляции**. И, как правило,
  хранятся в сегменте данных, либо оптимизируются до константы прямо в
  сегменте кода, если к ним нет обращения из других мест.
- Все локальные переменные или по другому динамические, не требующие
  конструирования как правило создаются и инициализируются в стеке
  своей локализации. Т.е. переменная внутри функции создается в стеке
  этой функции. Такие переменные создаются **при вхождении в функцию или 
  блок** и уничтожаются при выходе во время выполнения программы.
- Все переменные (объекты) требующие конструирования, соответственно
  **конструируются во время выполнения программы.** Глобальные во время
  старта программы, локальные после их создания в месте их локализации.

---

Теперь, что касается данного вопроса

```
int main() {
    /*
        некоторый код
    */
    ...{
        static int someVal = 42;
    }
}
```

Переменная *someVal* будет создана и инициализирована во время компиляции. Если к ней не будет обращений то и вовсе будет нивелирована до константы или даже удалена. Ели к ней будет обращение то, скорее всего, она будет размещена в сегменте данных. 
На этапе компиляции обращение к данной переменной будет ограничено только из ее блока. ***И так как к ней в данном конкретном случае нет никаких обращений то она будет просто удалена даже не попав в код программы.***

Comment: В С++ вообще нет такого понятия, как "создание и инициализация на стадии компиляции". И хотя мы иногда используем подобный неформально-дворовый сленг в контекстах, где его смысл понятен, ваши попытки противопоставить этот сленг строгой формальной терминологии ни к чему ценному не приведут. Также, автор вопроса уточнил позже, что его намерением было задать общий вопрос о моменте создания локальных статических объектов любых типов, а тип `int` был выбран лишь в качестве (неудачного) примера. Общий вопрос вы в своем ответе не раскрыли вообще. И это после такого эпического вступления?

Comment: Мне жаль,что я задел Ваши нежные чувства. Подобными комментариями Вы только закапываете себя еще глубже. Лично я считаю, что ответил на вопрос и в целом  и в частности. Что касается ваших замечаний, о сленге и т.п. то почитайте например стандарт С++ или какие нибудь учебники. В С++ стандарте раздел 2.2 фаза 8. Вот тут есть разъяснения, что такое, например, компиляция [https://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html]

Comment: Вы задели нежные чувства локальных статических переменных, а не мои. Они (локальные статические), боюсь, сейчас плачут. Я же тем временем с энтузиазмом бросился открывать для себя доселе неизвестные уголки стандарта языка С++, но к сожалению не обнаружил обещанных вами жемчужин в "разделе 2.2 фаза 8". Печаль. Хотя у меня сразу вызвал определенное подозрения тот факт, что некто, изначально отпускавший саркастические ремарки на тему классических стандартных концепций времени жизни и периода хранения, вдруг бросился давать ссылки на... стандарт. Парадокс?