# Какие действия гарантированно выполнены к моменту передачи управления первому оператору функции main()?

Tags: c++, c

Какие действия гарантированно выполнены к моменту передачи управления первому оператору функции main()?

Comment: экзамен? ответ на этот вопрос достаточно ещё компиляторозависимый.

Comment: @KoVadim: Стандарт вполне себе предписывает поведение при старте: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start

Comment: этого никто не исключает. я на написад "ещё". Но для начала нужно понять, что нужно автору вопроса - ответить на экзамене или пофиксить багу.

Comment: @KoVadim: Или просто разобраться? Например, можно ли в функции, вызываемой до `main`, использовать `cout`, или это UB.

Comment: @KoVadim Видеокурс прохожу и нужно разобраться. Компилятор по умолчанию gcc.

Comment: Ответ - все инициализаторы, static инициализаторы классов в том числе.

Answer (score 1):

До момента начала выполнения `main()` гарантированно будет выполнена инициализация глобальных переменных, а также статических членов классов.

Порядок этих инициализаций между различными единицами трансляции не определён.

Comment: А внутри единицы трансляции?

Comment: @VladD внутри - в порядке определения. Но зависит ещё от того, какого рода эта инициализация: статическая или динамическая. Статическая будет выполнена раньше динамической.

Answer (score 1):

В моем случае правильным ответом оказалось следующее:

1. Создан и запущен начальный поток процесса, ассоциированный с
   функцией main(). Как и написано в стандарте в коменте

   > Стандарт вполне себе предписывает поведение при старте: [eel.is/c++draft/basic.start](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start)
2. Переменные со статической продолжительностью хранения инициализированы. Это также прописано в стандарте
3. Параметры функции main() содержат количество и значения параметров вызова программы.
4. Переменные со статической продолжительностью хранения размещены в оперативной памяти.

Comment: Локальные статические переменные будут инициализированы в момент первого вызова кода их содержащего. Так что п.2 не совсем верен. Рекомендую ознакомиться с [замечательным ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/648438/176217) по этому поводу.  `main()` и `main(int, char*[])` всё же разные функции. В первом случае ни о каких параметрах вызова речи быть не может. Так что п.3. тоже неточен. Про оперативную память в стандарте языка ничего не говорится.